# I want to parse a string and get a double value (java)

Tags: java, double, java.util.scanner

I want to parse a string and get a double value.
For example, I input "65.2 hello".
I want to get "65.2"
Will I?

```
 while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  String ReadString =  scanner.nextLine();
  double value = Double.parseDouble(ReadString);

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "65.2 hello"
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Comment: `hello` obviously isn't a numerical value.  You could use a second `Scanner` to parse the line of text or you could split the string on the white space or handle the exception

Comment: You could use a regex to remove the non-number characters and then try to parse it. Something Like: str.replaceAll("[^\\d.-]", "");

Answer (score 0):

Because at least part of the String can't be converted to a double, you need to remove that part of the String before you can use parseDouble on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("65.2 hello");
while(scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
      double value =  scanner.nextDouble();
      System.out.println(value);
}
```

output:

```
65.2
```

Comment: doesnt work in my IDEA. silent

Answer (score 0):

For a simple string like `"65.2 hello"` where there is one numerical value within the string then a simple:

```
String myString = "65.2 hello";
double value = Double.parseDouble(myString.replaceAll("[^(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)]", "").trim());
```

should be suffice. But, if there is more than one numerical value within the string then you would need to change it up a little, for example:

```
String myString = "I weigh 90.7185kg and I would like to loose another 10kg. "
                + "My name is Tom, I'm 32 years old.";

String parsable = myString.replaceAll("[^(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)]", " ").trim()
                          .replaceAll("\\s\\p{Punct}|\\p{Punct}\\s", "");

double[] values = {};
if (!parsable.isEmpty()) {
    String[] numbers = parsable.split("\\s+");
    values = new double[numbers.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        values[i] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[i]);
    }
}

// Display doubles array into Console Window:
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Value #" + (i + 1) + " in String is: -> " + values[i]);
}
```

About the Regular Expressions (regex's) used in this line:

```
String parsable = myString.replaceAll("[^(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)]", " ").trim()
                          .replaceAll("\\s\\p{Punct}|\\p{Punct}\\s", "");
```

The `.replaceAll("[^(-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)]", " ").trim()` will replace everything within the String except for signed or unsigned Integer or floating point numerical values with a whitespace. It then trims the outcome of **leading** and or **trailing** whitespaces, tabs, etc (if any).

The `.replaceAll("\\s\\p{Punct}|\\p{Punct}\\s", "");` will replace any remaining special characters like punctuation that contains a least one leading or one trailing whitespace. When the first `replaceAll()` above has completed there is most likely going to be straggling periods, etc remaining in the string. We don't want those for splitting the string so this `replaceAll()` will get rid of those stragglers.

All that should now remain in the string will be numerical values separated by one or more whitespaces. This is where the regex `\\s+` used in the String#split() method comes in handy:

```
 String[] numbers = parsable.split("\\s+");
```

This will split the new string based on **one or more** whitespaces. So, what is     `"90.7185          10           32"` will be split into a String[] Array consisting of three elements, ["90.7185", "10", "32"]. Each element of this array is now converted to a **double** data type and added to the double type `values[]` Array.